# When using EF Fluent API to map my entities relationships, do I need to map on both entities involved?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm creating the entity relationships using Code First with EF Fluent API following the instructions from [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to create the 1:n and m:n relationships in my model.

What I'm wondering and haven't found a response searching, is that if it's required to define the relationship on both ends of it.

By that I mean, if I have an entity called User and Organization, there are two relationships involving these two entities as I described below:

- An User can many Organizations, while an Organization must be owned by one User.
- An User may be present in many Organizations, while an Organization may have many Users in it.

With this in mind, I defined the relationships using Fluent API as follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasRequired(o => o.Owner).WithMany(u => u.OrganizationsOwned).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<Organization>(u => u.Organizations).WithMany(o => o.Users).Map(uo =>
        {
            uo.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            uo.MapRightKey("OrganizationId");
            uo.ToTable("OrganizationsUsers");
        });
```

But are these definitions enough? Or do I have to define the relationships on the other end of the entities too? What I mean, do I need to add the following code?

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.OrganizationsOwned).WithRequired(o => o.Owner).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasMany<User>(o => o.Users).WithMany(u => u.Organizations).Map(ou =>
        {
            ou.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            ou.MapRightKey("OrganizationId");
            ou.ToTable("OrganizationsUsers");
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you just try? And then, while searching, you should have seen many examples were only one mapping statement is used for a bidirectional relationship (by which I also answer your question).

Comment: I tried, but no errors nor exceptions were thrown when running the service, because of that I got dubious at my implementation, since I'm not that familiar with AutoMapper usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these definitions are enough.  You are defining both sides of the relationship with the single statement:

```
.Entity<Organization>().HasRequired(o => o.Owner).WithMany(u => u.OrganizationsOwned)
```

The .HasRequired defines the 1 side, and the .WithMany defines the Many side.  There is only one relationship, but two sides.  You can define the relationship from either side, but you do not have to define it from both.

Comment: another doubt I have is if any AutoMapper configuration is required when dealing with enum type properties?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - AutoMapper is never required to use EF.

Comment: my mistake, I meant Fluent API, sorry I've just started to use Azure Mobile Services and since both, Fluent API and AutoMapper are used I tend to mix them. So do I need to define a configuration with Fluent API when dealing with enum type properties?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - No, EF will detect the Enum in your code.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: So I only have to define my mapping with AutoMapper and the rest is done by EF with no influence from Fluent API?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - I really don't understand what your point about AutoMapper is... AutoMapper has nothing to do with this.

Comment: It seems I'm over thinking things, I should keep both things separated